# problema con LRUcache en javaScript

Tags: javascript, java

estoy aplicando par aun apleo y no logro relizar el siguente ejercicio.
Haga que la función LRUCache ( strArr ) tome la matriz de caracteres almacenados en strArr , que contendrá caracteres que van de la A a la Z en algún orden arbitrario, y determine qué elementos aún permanecen en una caché virtual que puede contener hasta 5 elementos con una LRU algoritmo de caché implementado. Por ejemplo: si strArr es ["A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "E", "D", "Z"], se siguen los siguientes pasos:

(1) A no existe en el caché, así que acceda a él y guárdelo en el caché.
(2) B no existe en el caché, así que acceda a él y guárdelo también en el caché. Hasta ahora, el caché contiene: ["A", "B"].

(4) Lo mismo ocurre con D, por lo que el caché ahora es: ["A", "B", "C", "D"].
(5) Ahora se accede a A de nuevo, pero ya existe en la caché, por lo que se lleva al frente: ["B", "C", "D", "A"].
(6) E no existe en el caché, así que acceda a él y guárdelo en el caché: ["B", "C", "D", "A", "E"].
(7) Se accede de nuevo a D para que se coloque al frente: ["B", "C", "A", "E", "D"].
(8) Z no existe en el caché, así que agréguelo al frente y elimine el elemento utilizado menos recientemente: ["C", "A", "E", "D", "Z"].

Ahora se han completado los pasos de almacenamiento en caché y su programa debe devolver el orden del caché con los elementos unidos en una cadena, separados por un guión. Por lo tanto, para el ejemplo anterior, su programa debe devolver CAEDZ .

````
    this.value = value;
    this.next = next;
  }
  
  function LRUCache(strArr){
    var final;
    let matriz = strArr;
    this.size = 0;
    this.head = null;
    this.tail = null;
    this.capacity = 5;
    /*this.cache = [];*/

    if (strArr){
      var key = Object.keys(strArr)[0];

      var value = strArr[key];
      /*cache(key, value);*/
    }
    
  
  

  /*esta vacio//*/
  LRUCache.prototype.isEmpty = function(){
    return this.head == null && this.tail == null;
  }

  /*añadir primero*/
  LRUCache.prototype.addFirst = function(obj){
    var newNode = new Node(obj, null);
    if(this.isEmpty()){
      this.head = this.tail = newNode;
    }else{
      this.head.next = newNode;
      this.head = newNode;

    }
    this.size++;
    newNode = null;
  }

  /*eliminar final*/
  LRUCache.prototype.removeLast = function(){
    if (!this.isEmpty()){
      var key = Object.keys(this.tail.value)[0];
      delete this[key];
      this.tail = this.tail.next;

      if(this.tail == null){
        this.head = null;
      }
      this.size--;
    }
  }

  /*mover al frente*/
  LRUCache.prototype.moveForward = function(key){
    var node = this.search(key);

    if(node && node.next){
      var next = node.next;
      var temp = node.value;
      node.value = next.value;
      next.value = temp;
    }
  }

  /*eliminar de cache*/
  
  LRUCache.prototype.cache = function(key, value){
    
    var result = this.search(key);

    if (result){
      result.value[key] = value;
      this[key] = value;
    }else{
      var obj = {};
      obj[key] = value;
      this.addFirst(obj);
      var that = this;

      Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
        set : function(x) {
          that.moveForward(key);
          value = x;
        },

        get : function(){
          that.moveForward(key);
          return value;
        },
        configurable : true,
        enumerable : true

      });

      if (this.size > this.capacity){
        this.reoveLast();
      }
    
    
    }
    return this;
    /*return matriz;*/
  }

  /* Eliminiar*/
  LRUCache.prototype.del = function(key) {
    if (this.search(key)){
      var previous = null;
      var cur = this.tail;
      for (; cur; cur = cur.next) {
        if(cur.value.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        break;
      }
      previous = cur;
    }
    if(previous){
      if(previous.next){
        previous.next = previous.next.next;
        this.size--;
      }
    }else{
      this.tail = this.tail.next;
      this.size--;
    }
      
    }else{
      if(this.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        return (delete this[key]);
      }else{
        return (delete LRUCache.prototype[key]);
      }
    }
    
  }

  /*encuentra elementos*/
  LRUCache.prototype.search = function(key){
    for (var e = this.tail; e; e=e.next){
      if(key in e.value){
        return e;
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
  return value;

}```
````

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar lo que has intentado hacer, no pretendas que lo hagan todo por ti. Edita tu pregunta haciendo clic en [edit] y agrega un [mcve], donde expongas con claridad el problema, el comportamiento actual y el resultado esperado. De lo contrario tu pregunta terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: Además, **javascript no es java, ni viceversa**.